# Контроль child в ExspandableList

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго времени суток.  Помогите пожалуйста решить 1н вопрос, с (изменением child в реальном времени). Механизм:

- в Create заполняется список Groups, а Childs (пока, остается пустым);
- после клика, Grups должно развернутся и с генерировать список childs;

У меня получился вот такой код, Grups заполняется и реагирует в логе на клик, а вот childs к сожалению так и остается пустым 8*( Буду рад выслушать опытных кодеров )

```
final static String Group_Pack= "groupPackage";
final static String Child_Pack= "childPackage";

String[] groups;
String[] childs;

ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;

    Map<String, String> m;

String childFrom[];
  int childTo[];

String groupFrom[];
  int groupTo[];

  static SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;
  ExpandableListView elvMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_norms);

    groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

      groups = new String[] { заполняю String... };
      for (String group : groups) {
       m = new HashMap<String, String>();
       m.put(Group_Pack, group);
       groupData.add(m);

        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {Group_Pack};
            int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
```

*На данном этапе child - пустует*

```
childFrom = new String[] {Child_Pack};
childTo = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                childFrom,
                childTo);

        elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvMain);
        elvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

  // Клик по Grups 
        elvMain.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
      public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
          int groupPosition, long id) {
                              ...............
          return true;
      }
    });

 // Разворачивание Groups
              elvMain.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
              public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

              childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>(); 
           childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

              childs = new String[] { заполняю String... };

              for (String child : childs) {
               m = new HashMap<String, String>();
               m.put(Child_Pack, child); 
              childDataItem.add(m); 
              childData.add(childDataItem);

  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да уж. Потом сопровождай вот такой код таких программистов:( 
извините, вырвалось!

Возьмите пример который есть в С:\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-16\ApiDemos....\ExpandableList1.java(путь для Windows) и сделайте по аналогии, разве это сложно?:

```
package com.example.android.apis.view;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

/**
 * Demonstrates expandable lists using a custom {@link ExpandableListAdapter}
 * from {@link BaseExpandableListAdapter}.
 */
public class ExpandableList1 extends ExpandableListActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.expandable_list_sample_action);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids. 
     * Each photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the
     * list of photos and adding a new photo.
     *
     */
    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
                { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
                { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
                { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
        };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(ExpandableList1.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```